# Docker - archive/tar: write too long

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am a Docker rookie, and facing an issue then I try to copy a Docker image from the Docker hub to my own Docker rep in Bluemix. I would like to copy the elastic search images from Docker hub:

https://github.com/docker-library/official-images

I log into a Bluemix from a CF commandline, and execute the command:

```
cf ic cpi docker.io/library/elasticsearch registry.ng.bluemix.net/ipsendemo/db_elasticsearch:new
```

But i got an error back, that says:

> archive/tar: write too long

Below is my request and the reponse back. Can anyone tell me the meaning of this error?

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>cf ic cpi docker.io/library/elasticsearch registry.ng.bluemix.net/ipsendemo:new
C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\docker422820463
archive/tar: write too long
```

Answer (score 1):

For the [Docker Hub](http://hub.docker.com) registry, you don't need to include the **docker.io/library** prefix when referencing images.

```
cf ic cpi elasticsearch registry.ng.bluemix.net/ipsendemo:new
```

This command-line will work.